# SCSS Показать картику при наведении на ссылку

Tags: css, sass, hover, бэм

ребята, подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать показ картинки при ховере на ссылку.
у меня есть меню с подменю, нужно что бы картинка отображалась при наведении на ссылку в подменю.

Рассчитывал это сделать без js

структура  html кода подменю:

```
<li class="nav__subMenuItem">
  <a href="" class="nav__subMenuItemLink">
     Pebble paper 
      <div class="nav__subMenuImgWrap">
      <img class="nav__subMenuImg" src="assets/dist/img/png/pebble_paper.png" alt="missed picture">
   </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4p5f06v9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.nav__subMenuImg {
  display: none;
}

.nav__subMenuItemLink:hover .nav__subMenuImg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav__subMenuItem">
  <a href="" class="nav__subMenuItemLink">
     Pebble paper 
      <div class="nav__subMenuImgWrap">
      <img class="nav__subMenuImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x150" alt="missed picture">
   </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласно описаной проблемы должно бить как то так

```
.nav__subMenuItemLink       .nav__subMenuImg { display: none;}
.nav__subMenuItemLink:hover .nav__subMenuImg { display: inline-block;}
```

Предоставьте пример на jsfidde и уточните требования если ето не то

Comment: https://codepen.io/Kostya_vasin/pen/GyVERG

Comment: я хотел все на сассе делать и по бэму что бы не было вложеностей. такая же ситуация с выпадающим меню, при наведении на wedding должно появиться под меню, и при наведении на пункт Pebble paper  - картинка